# A question about WinForms versus WPF regarding GUI performance

Tags: gui

I have some experience with WinForms and want to make a GUI for real-time plot of signals and also controlling hardware.

I am planning to use WinForms for this and want to avoid WPF. My reasoning is that I don't need the outlook to be good looking but only functionality and performance.

In WinForms I have written before some small programs for similar purpose using built in WinForms charts and BackgroundWorker for the threading part. Otherwise the GUI was freezing.

My question is, does WPF have any performance advantage besides outlook? I am mostly interested in plotting live graphs like time series and FFT and saving the data real from serial ports.

Comment: There is no way to tell if WPF has any performance advantage *for your specific use case* without implementing two representative prototypes of *your specific use case*, one with WPF and another one using Winforms, and then measure the differences. And even then, I can imagine that both technologies are fast enough your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

WPF can use hardware-acceleration for displaying graphics (and plotting graphs). So especially when using larger amounts of graphic objects WPF can handle them better. In Forms you would have to go down to Win32-API/Buffered Images etc. to get better performance, and even then you would lack hardware-acceleration without using something like DirectX etc.

The code for calculations will have the same performance in Forms/WPF because both will be executed within the .NET-Runtime.
Threading will behave very similar, because this is mainly an OS-Task and not a GUI-Framework-Task.

WPF has a bit longer Application-Startup and larger Memory-Overhead. If thats relevant depends on your requirements.

I would highly recomment looking for some graph-libraries that support the kind of visualization you need - that can save a LOT of time rather than creating your own.

Maybe event some kind of 2D-gaming engine would be worth a look, they are (mostly) heavily optimized for performance.

Of course you have to do things like dispatching and backgroud work in both frameworks how its meant to be done - else you always will kill performance (like using the main-gui thread for heavy calculations, or too frequent/unessessary gui updates, etc.)